# Android WebView Unknown chromium error: -6

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a WebView in a fragment to only display animated gifs from my assets. Whenever I load a new url by pressing a button I get the error: Unknown chromium error: -6

Is there a specific cause to this?

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could say the reason is the URL is not found for example I am using phonegap , and when I load a resource by $.get(myUrl......)

It gives me the same error, when the path is  resolved correctly then the problem will be solved.

Also the file should be read as file:///android_asset/www/myUrl

Your code would be helpful